# How to make an anchor tag's href invoke an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I'm working on a cross-site scripting attack on an internet forum where links can be put in post like

```
[url]http://google.com[/url]
```

which then gets surfaced as

```
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
```

on the forum's thread. If possible, I want to use the technique of invoking JavaScript functions through the `href`, i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function sayHello ( )
    {
        alert("Hello");
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:sayHello()">Clicking here alerts "Hello"</a>
```

but since I don't have any way of using predefined JavaScript functions, I'm wondering if I can put anonymous functions in there, e.g.

```
<a href="javascript:function(){alert('Hellow');}">Clicking here alerts "Hello"</a>
```

I've tested this out in Notepad with the simple page

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Clicking on <a href="javascript:function(){alert('Hello');}">this</a> will alert "Hello""</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it didn't work.

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: Put an IIFE in the `href`.

Comment: And if you don't know what an IIFE is, you're not really a Javascript coder.

Comment: @Barmar Tried `javascript:(function(){alert('Hello');}())` and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar Is there any way I can use this to get a function to fire when the document is ready?

Comment: You can use `<body onload="code">` to execute code when the page is loaded.

Comment: But if the only thing you have control over is `href` attributes, I don't think there's any way to make it fire spontaneously. It only fires when someone clicks on the link.

Comment: @Barmar I can't write any tags. All I can do is write stuff that gets put in the href of an `a` tag.

Comment: Why do you need to invoke a function? What's wrong with `href="javascript:alert('Hello')"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){stuff to do})()">Click here</a>
```

Although there's not too much difference from doing this without the IIFE, just as top-level JS code:

```
<a href="javascript:stuff to do">Click here</a>
```

The only significant difference is that you can declare local variables within the function.